# packery.js with a couple other js packages and trying to use fit to place an item on click to the center of the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, packery

I have built a packery.js instance inside of a flickity.js instance inside of fullpage.js instance.

Everything works beautifully except I cannot get the packery method fit on click to move the clicked item (which is also expanding) to the center of the viewport. [Working Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/6SQhb/68/)

I have even tried scrollTo and scrollTop - in other times.

[Here is my code in a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6SQhb/68/) The packery instance is on the second section - you will have to swipe down to get to it.

Please help! And if you could so I can learn more, let me know how you figured out what is conflicting or wrong.

Code Pen Example

```
 $container.packery( 'fit', event.target, 80, 80 );
```

My code example

starts line 115

```
  //works
     //$container.packery();

    //doesnt work
    $container.packery('fit', '.element-item', 80,80 );
```

Comment: Have you tried to initialize your plugin inside the `afterRender` callback of fullPage.js? Read [the fullpage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions).

Comment: I have but I just did it again and it still does not work. "Just in case"

Comment: This is the working example - since it is missing above http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/fguJH

Comment: The simple explanation of what I found is that the working codepen example was using `event.target` and I was using `'.element-item'`. The method needed a dom reference.  So this is what fixed the error : `var domElement = $( this ).get( 0 );
    $container.packery( 'fit', domElement, 400, 0 );`